# Mechanize and invisible search form

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to perform search on some website using Mechanize but I can't submit a search form because mechanize does not see any forms. `page.form` returns nil and `page = agent.get` returns just `{forms}>` while I expect something like

```
<Mechanize::Form
 {name "somename"}
 {method "GET"}
 {action "/search"}
```

Is it because the search form uses javascript? Is there any way to solve this? Or the only way is to give up on mechanize and use something else?

Comment: Mechanize cannot do javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript

Comment: Could you post the URL to the page you're trying to crawl? Unixmonkey is absolutely right. You can also use a webdriver (like waitir) to load the page first.

Comment: This is the page http://s.weibo.com/ I knew that mechanize had problems with js but I was not sure if this specific problem was because of js. And I hoped that there's possible some workaround... For mechanize seems to be perfect for my needs and the idea of using something else makes me sad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means there's no form on that page. The workaround is to `get` the next page, the one that's pretending to be a form submit.

In other words when I type 'foo' into the search box and click the button I get redirected to:
http://s.weibo.com/weibo/foo&Refer=index
So just `get` that page and do something with it.