# Use nokogiri or mechanize to parse emails, which are rendered using JavaScript

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html-parsing, nokogiri, mechanize

I want to parse email addresses which are rendered this way:

```
<p class="email">
"Email: "
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
 document.write('f'+'o'+'<wbr/>@'+'e'+'x'+'p'+'.'+'c'+'o'); //-->
</script>
</p>
```

I'm using this code:

```
task import_emails: :environment do
  require 'mechanize'
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.get("URL")
  agent.page.search(".email").each do |email|
    puts email.text.strip
  end
end
```

It only returns "Email: ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri/Mechanize do not handle JavaScript, so the email text that you add with `document.write` is not visible to them and that's why you only get `Email:` back.

If you want to select elements or text that are rendered using JavaScript, you'll have to consider tools that actually drive a browser, so that you get the page rendered with JavaScript. One example would be [Watir](http://watir.com/). Also, take a look at [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) and [Capybara webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit).

See "[How do I use Mechanize to process JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript)" for more details.

Comment: Thanks, Watir is good option, I already installed it and it seems I can capture javascript functions

Comment: I added capybara-webkit as well, if you want something that doesn't require a browser actually being open all the time (which can be annoying).