# Calling js function using Browser from mechanize in python

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am working on a web-scraping project. I am using Browser from mechanize in python. I need to call a JavaScript function with two arguments. The arguments are known.

```
    __doPostBack(arg1,arg2)
```

How do i call this function from Python?

Comment: Mechanize currently doesn't support Javascript.

Comment: what should i use then?

Comment: Can't you print out javascript in a `<script>` with pyton, and concatenate the variables you need into the function's params?

Comment: RK Poddar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript