# Ruby Script unable to gather data

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# Fetches all Virginia Tech classes from the timetable and spits them out into a nice JSON object
# Can be run with option of which file to save output to or will save to classes.json by default
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'

#Create Mechanize Browser and Class Data hash to load data into
agent = Mechanize.new
classData = Hash.new

#Get Subjects from Timetable page
page = agent.get("https://banweb.banner.vt.edu/ssb/prod/HZSKVTSC.P_ProcRequest")
subjects = page.forms.first.field_with(:name => 'subj_code').options

#Loop subjects
subjects.each do |subject|

#Get the Timetable Request page & Form
timetableSearch = agent.get("https://banweb.banner.vt.edu/ssb/prod/HZSKVTSC.P_ProcRequest")
searchDetails = page.forms.first

#Submit with specific subject 
searchDetails.set_fields({
    :SUBJ_CODE => subject,
    :TERMYEAR => '201401',
    :CAMPUS => 0
})

#Submit the form and store results into courseListings
courseListings = Nokogiri::HTML(
    searchDetails.submit(searchDetails.buttons[0]).body
)

#Create Array in Hash to store all classes for subjects
classData[subject] = [] 

#For every Class
courseListings.css('table.dataentrytable/tr').collect do |course|

    subjectClassesDetails = Hash.new

    #Map Table Cells for each course to appropriate values
    [
        [ :crn, 'td[1]/p/a/b/text()'],
        [ :course, 'td[2]/font/text()'],
        [ :title, 'td[3]/text()'],
        [ :type, 'td[4]/p/text()'],
        [ :hrs, 'td[5]/p/text()'],
        [ :seats, 'td[6]/text()'],
        [ :instructor, 'td[7]/text()'],
        [ :days, 'td[8]/text()'],
        [ :begin, 'td[9]/text()'],
        [ :end, 'td[10]/text()'],
        [ :location, 'td[11]/text()'],
    #   [ :exam, 'td[12]/text()']
    ].collect do |name, xpath|
        #Not an additional time session (2nd row)
        if (course.at_xpath('td[1]/p/a/b/text()').to_s.strip.length > 2)
            subjectClassesDetails[name] = course.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
        end
    end

    #Add class to Array for Subject!
    classData[subject].push(subjectClassesDetails)
end
end

#Write Data to JSON file
open(ARGV[0] || "classes.json", 'w') do |file| 
file.print JSON.pretty_generate(classData)
end
```

The above code is supposed to retrieve data from https://banweb.banner.vt.edu/ssb/prod/HZSKVTSC.P_ProcRequest
but if I print subjects.length is prints 0 so it clearly isn't getting the correct data. The given term code "201401" is definitely the right one.

I've noticed that when I manually enter in the link to my browser the subject field doesn't allow you to select an option until a term is selected, however when I view the page source the data is clearly already there. What can I do to retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at that vtech page and I can see that you need to select a TERMYEAR first before the `subj_code` dropdown fills allowing you to get the options. Unfortunately this happens with javascript in `function dropdownlist(listindex)`. Mechanize doesn't handle javascript so this script is doomed to fail.

Your options are to run a browser automator like Watir or Selenium: discussed here: [How do I use Mechanize to process JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript)

Or to read the source of that page and parse out the values of these lines:

```
document.ttform.subj_code.options[0]=new Option("All Subjects","%",false, false);
document.ttform.subj_code.options[1]=new Option("AAEC - Agricultural and Applied Economics","AAEC",false, false);
document.ttform.subj_code.options[2]=new Option("ACIS - Accounting and Information Systems","ACIS",false, false);
```

To get the options. You could do that by simply using `open-uri`:

```
require 'open-uri'
page = open("https://banweb.banner.vt.edu/ssb/prod/HZSKVTSC.P_ProcRequest")
page_source = page.read
```

Now you can use a regex to scan for all the options:

```
page_source.scan /document\.ttform.+;/
```

That'll give you an array with all the lines that have the javascript codes that contain the options. Craft your regex a little better and you can extract the option text from those. I'll see if I can come up with something for that and I'll post back. Hopefully this will get you headed in the right direction.

I'm back. I was able to parse out all the subj_code options with this regex:

```
subjects = page_source.scan(/Option\("(.*?)"/).uniq # remove duplicates
subjects.shift # get rid of the first option because it's just "All Subjects"
subjects.size == 137
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Theres no way to select the term that I want by changing the value of the form and then let it reload itself?

Comment: Nope, looking at the page source i can see that the subj_code only gets populated via javascript.

Comment: And as mentioned, Mechanize doesn't handle javascript. You won't be able to get this script working with it. You'll have to switch to one of the aforementioned gems.