# How do you click a label in a form in mechanize?

Tags: python, mechanize

```
<p class="field switch">
            <label id="on" class="cb-enable"><span>On</span></label>
            <label id="off" class="cb-disable selected"><span>Off</span></label>
</p>
```

Any idea how I can click the label with id="on"? It's a switch that I want to switch from off to on, by clicking the "on" label.

Things I've tried:

```
br.form.get(label="On").click()
br.form.find_control(id="on").click()
```

Documentation: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect as the result? There's no JS support in Mechanize AFAIK, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript.

Comment: The result should move `selected` to the `on` label. That's what happens when you click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanize has no javascript support so there is no click event to trigger. Also, the HTML you are showing doesn't contain a input element so mechanize can't do anything with it.

If Javascript is truly needed for this site than I'd recommend using [Watir](http://watir.com/), [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) or [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) with [ScrapyJS](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs)

With Mechanize you can manually edit the response like this:

```
import mechanize

class ReplacingOpener(mechanize.SeekableResponseOpener):
    def process_response_object(self, response):
        response = mechanize.SeekableResponseOpener.process_response_object(
            self, response)

        # Get the HTML from the response
        html = response.read()

        # Replace the HTML here with anything you feel like
        html = html.replace('</body>', '')

        # Set it back to the response
        response.set_data(html)
        return response


opener = mechanize.OpenerFactory(ReplacingOpener).build_opener()
response = opener.open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793091/')

forms = mechanize.ParseResponse(response)
print forms
```

Comment: Isn't there a way just to modify the browser-side source and submit it? I just need to get `selected` in the `on` label.

Comment: There's no clear documented way to modify the source, but you could do so using a custom opener, I'll write an example. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @macdonjo: look at the example I've added :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky with mechanize (see @Wolph's answer).

Why do you say that selenium is overkill? It would look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "http://www.dummy.com/page.html"
click_id = 'on'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id(click_id).click()
new_page = driver.page_source
```

Comment: FireFox on a little linux VPS I just think is overkill.

Comment: Yes you said that already. But, why? :p ...sry im a bit stubborn:-)