# How should I use this onclick(javascript) in Python

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize

I'm first time to ask questions here and I'm new to Python.

I install the mechanize and BeautifulSoup to change some forms from a page.

Now, I use `br.submit()` to send the request , it doesn't work!

Is there any way to call the `onclick` function(javascript)?

Here is the code about that button send data:

```
<div class="go_btm w_a1">
<p class="gogo"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:checkdata(document.mainform);" onkeypress="checkdata(document.mainform);">search</a></p>
<p class="gogo"><a href="#" onclick="reset();" onkeypress="reset();">cancel</a></p>
<br class="CLEAR" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Thank you for support the Selenium this tool.

But I have another problem. My code below:

`for i in range(len(all_options)): 
   arr.append(all_options[i])`

`count = 0
for option in arr:
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
    if count > 1:
        option.click()
        string = u'search'
        link2 = browser.find_element_by_link_text(string.encode('utf8'))
        response = link2.click()
        browser.back()
    count = count + 1`

After I back to the same page,it answer me:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc2\Desktop\TEST.py", line 44, in <module>
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 93, in get_attribute
    resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 385, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.111)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)`

I can only click the select once.

Is that talk me my option in the array disappear?

How should I keep the variable(option) let next loop to click?

Comment: The only sensible way to run javascript this way is to involve a browser (possibly headless) e.g with Selenium.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm first time here.
I'm trying to understand the tools

Comment: You did nothing wrong, no reason to apologize! I'm just giving the same info very concisely in a comment as @alexce did in their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mechanize` cannot handle javascript:

- [How do I use Mechanize to process JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript)

Instead, you can *automate a real browser* via [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('myurl')

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('search')
link.click()
```