# How this javascript variable is set

Tags: javascript, variables

I would like to know how a particular variable in a `<script>` tag is set. Because **even when I disable Javascript** in my browser, it is still set, I don't get how?

The variable can be found here: https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/

```
html > head > script > token
```

[image]

For more informations about why I need to understand this, [here is my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682494/get-javascript-variable-using-mechanize/29683748#29683748).

Comment: Maybe an input from server-side?

Comment: Edit your question to be relevant, don't just open new ones.

Answer (score 0):

The OP said "when I get this page" which suggests the token value is being PLACED into the page from the server side.  I don't think they mean set in JavaScript itself.