# How can I use mechanize to click button to webscrape a page to get information?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm looking to scrape the contents of a page that requires you to press an arrow button in which, information will appear via jquery rather than loading a new page. Since there needs to be a button click, I'm using mechanize for this part instead of nokogiri. What I have so far is

```
url = "http://brokercheck.finra.org/Individual/Summary/1327992"
mechanize = Mechanize.new 
page = mechanize.get(url)
button = page.at('.ArrowExpandDsclsr.faangledown')
new_page = mechanize.click(button)
new_page.at('#disclosuredetails')
```

It appears that new_page still doesn't show the page with the newly loaded information. Anyone know why that is?

Comment: Mechanize does not process Javascript. Have a look at the answers for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button you're trying to get mechanize to click is not a "regular" button, it's a bit more dynamic. It uses javascript / ajax to fetch the relevant data when clicked.

Mechanize doesn't render the DOM of a web page nor it provides a way to have javascript interact with the page. Thus it's not suitable for interacting with dynamic pages depending on javascript for their functionality.

For such cases, I'd suggest [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), either standalone or through [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) / [poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) if you'd prefer interacting with it via ruby.