# Call onclick Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

How can I call onclick method instead of submit using ruby Mechanize?

```
<input type="Submit" value="Search" name="B2" onclick="getABC()">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Mechanize to process JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't, mechanize doesn't run javascript. use selenium or phantom