# How to setTimeout in mechanize ruby?

Tags: ruby, settimeout, mechanize

i want to use setTimeout in mechanize ruby for full page load.

i have try following. but didn't work

```
mech = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.open_timeout   = 5
  agent.read_timeout   = 5
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's also an idle_timeout but I'm not sure what the difference is or if it really works:

```
mech.methods.grep /timeout=/
#=> [:idle_timeout=, :open_timeout=, :read_timeout=]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're trying to use the `setTimeout` method from JavaScript, but unfortunately, Mechanize doesn't understand JavaScript and can't really work with it (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802225/2636454) for more info). The methods that you're using are separate from the `setTimeout` functionality in JavaScript. You might have success with something like this using [Watir](http://watir.github.io) or something similar:

```
# this assumes that `browser' is a `Watir::Browser' object
browser.execute_script("window.setTimeout(my_code, 2000)")
```